# How to check npm packages installed globally on my computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

We can check local dependencies in the `package.json` file, but I want to know how to figure out which global packages are installed on my windows machine through `npm`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to check globally installed `npm` modules. You use

```
npm list -g
```

to list all globally installed modules, along with their dependencies. If you just want to list the modules, use this command,

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Comment: thank you
"npm list -g --depth=0" was whatever i want